# How to add a legend entry for an errorbar in a barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if it is possible to do the following in R:

I am doing a dodged barchart and using the geom error bar. I am currently using the following example:

```
df <- read.table(
text = 
"group metric somevalue
T1 epsilon 63
T2 epsilon 91
T1 kappa 19
T2 kappa -3
T1 zulu  -5
T2 zulu 8", header=TRUE)

str(df)

df$metric <- factor(df$metric, levels = c("kappa", "zulu", "epsilon"))

df2 <- read.table(
text = 
"group metric deviation
T1 epsilon 20
T2 epsilon 10
T1 kappa 10
T2 kappa 20
T1 zulu  25
T2 zulu 10", header=TRUE)

lower <- df$somevalue - df2$deviation/2
head(lower)
upper <- df$somevalue + df2$deviation/2
head(upper)

thePlot <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=metric, y=somevalue, fill=group)) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') + coord_flip() + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
       legend.text=element_text(size=14),
       legend.title = element_blank(),
       axis.title.x = element_blank(),
       axis.title.y = element_blank())+ 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC6600", "steelblue")) + ylim(-20, 100) + geom_errorbar(aes(x = metric, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), position=position_dodge(1), width = 0.2, size = 1, color = "black") 
thePlot
```

[image]

I would like to add a label next to the color labels but showing the line element (geom error) as well. The final outcome should look like the following (Showing a line and std error label in the legend):

[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the color of the error bar as argument map on the `color` aesthetic, which will automatically give you a legend entry, and set the color and/or label via `scale_color_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = metric, y = somevalue, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CC6600", "steelblue")) +
  ylim(-20, 100) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = metric, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = "error"), position = position_dodge(1), width = 0.2, size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(error = "black"), labels = c(error = "Standard Error"))
```

[image]